# Assigning subvectors to multidimensional arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

Say I have a matrix:

```
from numpy import *
a = zeros(shape=(nRows,nColumns));
```

and I would like to fill in the first column with ones, when I try to do:

```
a[:][0] = ones(shape=(nRows,1))
```

I get:

```
ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: The existing answer is correct. But just to answer your question as to "why is this not working", you're trying to cram an nRows x 1 array into a single row.  In other words, you're trying to fit a single-column, multi-row array into one row.  In any case, don't do that.  And also use comma-indexing instead of multiple [][] indexing--the latter makes wasteful intermediate array objects for each additional pair of [].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be as easy as:

```
a[:,0] = 1
```

[broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) will handle the details.

```
>>> a = np.zeros((10,10))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> a[:,0]=1
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```